# Finding the difference between two dates in a set timezone

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to make a timer that counts down time time left of the week in a set timezone. Originally, I did it with PHP, however I am trying to do it with just Javascript. Originally I used this code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');
$days = (new DateTime())->diff(new DateTime('1970-01-04'))->format('%a');
$week = ceil($days/7)-2544;
$day = ceil($days/7)*7 - $days;
$hour = 24-(new DateTime())->diff(new DateTime('00:00:00'))->format('%H');
```

I wanted it to give the the weeks since a set week, that's why it has `$week =...-2544` giving 24 or 25 or something this week. My problem is I can't figure out how to do this in pure Javascript.

At the moment I have this:

```
var time = new Date().toLocaleString("en-GB",{timeZone:"Australia/Sydney"});
```

which gives me `26/03/2019 11:31:52` as at the last time I ran the function.

By then using

```
var time = new Date(-1*1000*60*60*10).toLocaleString("en-GB",{timeZone:"Australia/Sydney"});
```

to give me `0/0/1970 00:00:00`

I have the two dates I need to find the difference between.

My problem is I can't seem to figure out how to find this difference. It doesn't seem to let me use `.getTime()` and I think that might be because the dates might just be strings that I need to somehow format to work, like what is done in the PHP.

Anyone able to help me find the difference in milliseconds?

Comment: you'd subtract one Date object from the other - the answer is in milliseconds

Comment: subtracting the two variables I put there come up as NaN because they are strings, so I cant just do that. I need to convert it to a date somehow

Comment: `new Date` does not return a string - perhaps you should show the code you're having an issue with ... is it the PHP code, or is it javascript code you haven't shown?

Comment: the php is what I originally used but now I want to do with javascript. The var statements are the code I am having issues with

Comment: I misread your code, of course you have a string, `toLocaleString` does that ... don't do `toLocaleString` and you'll be fine ... if you want to display the dates, use different variable for the string representation to the one you will use to calculate the difference on

Comment: `to give me 0/0/1970 00:00:00` surely you mean `to give me 1/1/1970 00:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

You can perform maths (+, - etc) on Date objects

So use Date objects, and if you need the string version, store in another variable

```js
    var time1 = new Date();
    var time1String = time1.toLocaleString("en-GB",{timeZone:"Australia/Sydney"});
    var time2 = new Date(-1*1000*60*60*10);
    var time2String = time2.toLocaleString("en-GB",{timeZone:"Australia/Sydney"});
    console.log(`The difference between ${time1String} and ${time2String} is ${time1-time2}ms`);
```